# civix civicrm:ping error [Exception] Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php

Tags: extension, civicrm-buildkit, civix

I just installed CiviCRM BuildKit using the instructions [here](https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker)

After accessing the bash shell of the container with:

```
docker-compose exec -u buildkit civicrm bash
```

I try running the command

```
civix civicrm:ping
```

in the /src folder, I get the error

> [Exception]
>   Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configurations may interfere. To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.

How can I get the command(s) to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool - in the drupal site root of the site  you should see a folder "sites" and be able to see a file at sites/default/civicrm.settings.php  can you try running the command from the same directory as the civicrm.settings.php file.

Answer (score 2):

The `/build/dmaster/web/sites/default` folder has the civicrm.settings.php file, you can execute the commands from anywhere in/or below the `web` directory. This will allow civix to correctly locate the settings file.